# Is there a way for a ComboBox to remember a class instead of just a string in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

For example if I have something like a combobox with 3 options. Instead of passing strings to the values option like:

```
ttk.Combobox(master, values = ['1', '2', '3'])
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
ttk.Combobox(master, values = [class1, class2, class3])
```

I know if I override the _ _ str _ _ property of the class I'll be able to output a value, but it won't remember the actual class.

I find myself having to create a dictionary for classes like so to get the appropriate class I need when a customer select a value from the combobox.

```
myDict = {'1': class1, '2': class2, '3': class3}
```

Comment: I think this is the right way to do it.

Comment: Fair enough, I just wanted to poke around to see if there was a way to eliminate the need for a dictionary.